# Who writes the xml code when developing an Android app, the designer or developer?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a UI Designer and I'm starting to design layouts for Android Apps.
When I finalized the layout of the App, I sent the image files to the developer and he said that I should also write the XML codes, so that he would use it with JAVA. It happens that I don't know about XML code or JAVA. For what I saw, XML is more for the developer side than for the designer side. Do I really need to learn how to do a XML or should I talk to the developer so he could help me in this issue?

Comment: An android developer should know both :)

Comment: It's IMHO not your job to do the XML. Layout requires a lot of knowledge how different resources / configurations are used, how layout can be done efficiently etc. The developer should know all those details.

Comment: If the dev wanted that dev probably should have made sure before tasking you with this that you did indeed know xml and provided you with lots of info as described by zapl.

Comment: You two need to work this out together.

Answer (score 3):

> When I finalized the layout of the App, I sent the image files to the
>   developer and he said that I should also write the XML codes, so that
>   he would use it with JAVA.

What you have created is a `mockup`. It may or may not be fully realizable as a UI.

In android development, UI is designed using xml. To be able to design for android, you must know what components (widgets) are at your disposal, what properties these components have, and how they behave in relation to their siblings, parent, children etc. All of this can be done in xml *and* Java. To keep design and implementation separate, xml is used for the former.

So, in short, xml code should come from you.

> Do I really need to learn how to do a XML or should I talk to the
>   developer so he could help me in this issue?

If you want to get into designing for android, I would suggest you read through this: [Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

You'll see that writing xml for android is nothing but setting values to properties of components. You'll also find that there's a lot to discover and an almost flat learning curve.